# Format of a JSON response with Python

Tags: python, json

I've been working on a side-project and I've been struggling with extracting data from a JSON response using Python. Whatever I come up with, I can't seem to have a proper formatted JSON result (probably because I'm new to Python, so I could use some guidance)

With these few lines I query an API and write the response to a file:

```
response = client.get_products()
with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(response))
```

The generated json file reads as follows:

### Output

```
{
  'version': 'value',
  'list': [
    '{
        "product":
          {
            "attributes":
              {
                "name":"value",
                "location":"value"
              },
            "description":"text productA"
          },
        "version":"value"
    }',
    '{
        "product":
          {
            "attributes":
              {
                "name":"value",
                "location":"value"
              },
            "description":"text productB"
          },
        "version":"value"
    }'
  ],
 'date':'value'
}
```

That does not look like valid JSON, notice the single quotes... but, all within `{"product":...}` looks fine. So i tried another approach:

```
response = client.get_products()
with open('file.json', 'w') as output:
    json.dump(response, output)
```

This time the json file contains the following:

### Output

```
{
  "version": "value", 
  "list": [
    "{
        \"product\":
          {
            \"attributes\":
              {
                \"name\":\"value\",
                \"location\":\"value\"
              },
            \"description\":\"text productA\"
          },
        \"version\":\"value\"
    }", 
    "{
        \"product\":
          {
            \"attributes\":
              {
                \"instanceType\":\"value\",
                \"location\":\"value\"
              },
            \"description\":\"text productB\"
          },
        \"version\":\"value\"
    }"            
  ], 
  "date": "value"
}
```

Hmmm, not what I had in mind either...

**Question:** What am I doing wrong? and more important, how can I write the response to a valid formatted JSON file? So expected outcome should be:

### Expected output

```
{
  "version": "value",
  "list": [
    {
        "product":
          {
            "attributes":
              {
                "name":"value",
                "location":"value"
              },
            "description":"text productA"
          },
        "version":"value"
    }, 
    {
        "product":
          {
            "attributes":
              {
                "name":"value",
                "location":"value"
              },
            "description":"text productB"
          },
        "version":"value"
    }
  ], 
  "date": "value"
}
```

In the end I which to isolate all "product" entries in the response, bonus points for additional tips on how to achieve this :)

Comment: Is `response` an actual python dict? It looks like you're working with a string since it has both single and double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object contains *strings with JSON encoding*. Each element in the list referenced by the `list` key is a string object, that happens to hold valid JSON data. By using `json.dumps()` you encoded those strings to JSON values, so the use of backslashes is *entirely correct*; it is opaque data otherwise, it doesn't matter to the JSON encoder that the data is itself also valid JSON.

That those elements are JSON strings is probably an error *on the side of the service you called*. You now need to undo that mistake by decoding those JSON strings first:

```
response = client.get_products()
response['list'] = [json.loads(s) for s in response['list']]
with open('file.json', 'w') as output:
    json.dump(response, output)
```

If you also are responsible for the API output, fix that output. Don't double-encode your data.

As you discovered, using `str()` does not produce JSON output. That produces a *Python representation*, using valid Python syntax.

Comment: `get_products` is likely combining multiple Json encoded strings  as list elements.  You will either have to double decode on the caller side , or, more logically, change within `get_products` to decode the individual Json and then reencode the entire thing once.

Comment: @Martijn That makes sense, thank you for the explanation and adapted code, works like a charm! I'll get in touch with the owner of the API, or I should say the get_products function, as other functions provide by the API use correct encoding